# Calling Custom Writers Within Instance Methods: Why is self not implicit?

Tags: ruby

I am familiar with the conventional way of using `attr_accessors` within the `initialize` method:

```
class Dog
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end
end

dog = Dog.new("Denver")
p dog.name

=> "Denver"
```

I was playing around with custom `writers` and `readers`. I was suprised to realize the following:

- Within instance methods: you can call upon a `reader` method without explicitly specifying `self` because `self` is implicit.
- Within instance methods: you MUST explicitly call `self` to call upon a `writer` method. `self` IS NOT implicit for `attr_writers`

**Example 1** to show that `self` is implicit when calling `attr_reader` methods within instance methods:

```
class Dog
    def name
        @name
    end

    def name=(val)
        @name = val
    end

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def call_name
        # no need to say: p self.name
        p name
    end
end

dog = Dog.new("Denver")
dog.call_name

=> "Denver"
```

**Example 2** to show that `self` IS NOT implicit when calling upon `attr_writers` within instance methods.  In other words: the instance variable is not getting set because I did not prepend the `writer` method below with `self`:

```
class Dog
    def name
        @name
    end

    def name=(val)
        @name = val
    end

    def initialize(name_val)
        # works as expected with: self.name = name_val
        name = name_val 
    end

    def change_name
        # works as expected with: self.name = "foo"
        name = "foo"
    end
end

dog = Dog.new("Denver")
p dog.name

dog.change_name
p dog.name

=> nil
=> nil
```

**Question**: why isn't `self` implicit within instance methods when calling `attr_writers`? Why do I have to explicitly specify `self` for `attr_writers` within instance methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: why isn't `self` implicit within instance methods for
>   `attr_writers`?

Because defining a local variable takes precedence.

So here:

```
name = "foo"
```

you do not write an attribute, but defining a local variable `name`.

Comment: ahhh, thanks that makes much more sense now!